# value keeps on changing on menu item click inside the fragment in android

Tags: android, fragment, menuitem

I have a android project and I'm using a `fragment` that hosted by the `MainActivity` that extends to `AppCompatActivity`.

In my `fragment's menu`, I have an item there that i put a function that returns an int value.

```
case R.id.value:
     item.setChecked(true);
     valueReturned(100);
     return true;
default
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

inside the `valueReturned(int n)` function, I've simply multiply the `n` by `3` then return the `result`.

Now my problem is, every time I clicked that item (more than once) the function keeps on changing the value or keeps on increasing the returned result. Seems like it keeps on storing the first returned value then multiply it again every time I clicked the same menu item. Could someone here know how do I prevent this from happening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post valueReturned method?

Comment: @UdiIdan `valueReturned(int[] n) { for(int i = 0; i < n.lenght; i++) {n[i] = n[i] * 3} return n;}`

Comment: The valueReturned() method is declared as `public static int[] valueReturned(int[] n){}`. Thanks.